# Are there a progress with backporting Angular 2 Router into Angular 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute, ngcomponentrouter

As I understand ngComponentRouter (ngNewRouter) [has been deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngComponentRouter).
And I didn't find any other alternatives but ngRoute & ui-router, which are obviously not designed to work with [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but at that time as an alternative, the most popular was [ngrx/router](https://github.com/ngrx/router).

At the current point, Angular2 was released with its own [router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

**UPDATE**

AngularJS ui-router component based approach:

```
export function routeConfig($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider): void {
$stateProvider
    .state('app.details', {
        url: '/app/details',
        template: '<app-details></app-details>'
    })
    .state('app.item', {
        url: '/app/item',
        template: '<app-item></app-item>'
    })
    .state('app.error', {
        url: '/app/error',
        template: '<error></error>'
    })
}
```

Comment: The question is still actual.

Comment: So check last link in my answer

Comment: @mrded, yes, it was rewritten and works with components :)

Comment: Unfortunately, component router in AngularJS is still messy, so we are currently using TypeScript + AngularJS, and still `ui-router` with a specific component based implementation. Updated my answer.